# problems with sending jpg over http - node.js

Tags: http, node.js, jpeg, fs

I'm trying to write a simple http web server, that (among other features), can send the client a requested file.
Sending a regular text file/html file works as a charm. The problem is with sending image files.
Here is a part of my code (after parsing the MIME TYPE, and including fs node.js module):

```
if (MIMEtype == "image") {    
    console.log('IMAGE');  
    fs.readFile(path, "binary", function(err,data) {  
        console.log("Sending to user: ");  
        console.log('read the file!');  
        response.body = data;  
        response.end();  
    });  
} else {
    fs.readFile(path, "utf8", function(err,data) {
        response.body = data ;
        response.end() ;
    });
}
```

Why all I'm getting is a blank page, upon opening `http://localhost:<serverPort>/test.jpg`?

Comment: are you 100% sure that the file exists at `path`? you should `console.log(path)` and make sure that it points to a file that exists and has data in it.

Comment: @DaveRandom - Yeah - I was going to mention handling the err rather than just assuming it's worked.

Comment: @DaveRandom yea, I'm sure it is in there, and before calling that piece of code, I'm making sure the file indeed exist.

Comment: Are you saying that you get nothing from the server? If you view the request/response in something like [poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/), what headers do you see being returned from the server?

Comment: @DaveRandom is there something like this, but for chrome?

Comment: @limlim I use [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hplfkkmefamockhligfdcfgfnbcdddbg), there may be other, better solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a complete example on how to send an image with Node.js in the simplest possible way (my example is a gif file, but it can be used with other file/images types):

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    util = require('util'),
    file_path = __dirname + '/web.gif'; 
    // the file is in the same folder with our app

// create server on port 4000
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  fs.stat(file_path, function(error, stat) {
    var rs;
    // We specify the content-type and the content-length headers
    // important!
    response.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type' : 'image/gif',
      'Content-Length' : stat.size
    });
    rs = fs.createReadStream(file_path);
    // pump the file to the response
    util.pump(rs, response, function(err) {
      if(err) {
        throw err;
      }
    });
  });
}).listen(4000);
console.log('Listening on port 4000.');
```

**UPDATE:**

`util.pump` has been deprecated for a while now and you can just use streams to acomplish this:

```
fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(req);
```

Comment: I changed your image file to be my jpg file, and also changed the Content-Type to be 'image/jpeg', but nothig happens..

Comment: Now I see that stat.size is 0..why is that?

Comment: what node version are you using? is that image readable? is it corrupt.. ?

Comment: never mind, it works now this way (I used a bad picture). Do I have to use util.pump in my program?

Comment: As far as I know this is the recommended way (to use pump), even the Connect static middleware is using it: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/static.js#L193-195

Comment: util.pump=deprecated now